# asp.net application/IIS architecture

Tags: architecture

Hi:
I am working on a asp.net 3.5 portal application. One of the requirement is that:

1-Setting up 2 different urls
2-differentiating user types based on URLs

How can I achieve this in IIS 6.0? For example if user A will be directed from one avenue he will have different customization and branding vs user B.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

I would take a look at either [Umbraco](http://umbraco.org/) or [DotNetNuke](http://www.dotnetnuke.com/). A more lightweight approach would be to simply use the [themes and skins](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ykzx33wh.aspx) capability of ASP.Net.

HTH.